# Java: instance variable vs. local parameters

Tags: java, scope

I am puzzled by this:

```
private RenderingHints hints;

public void addRenderingHints(Map hints) {
    hints.putAll(hints);
}
```

(from http://dev.geogebra.org/trac/browser/trunk/geogebra/desktop/org/freehep/graphicsio/AbstractVectorGraphicsIO.java?rev=39574#L1238)

Both `Map` and `RenderingHints` have a `putAll` member functions:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/RenderingHints.html#putAll-java.util.Map-
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putAll-java.util.Map-

I have learned that local parameters can shadow instance variables. So what does this part of code do (useful)?

Comment: That's a mistake.  That code does not do what the author intended.

Comment: You can copy and paste that code into any Java IDE and check the behaviour

Comment: @bers: It's even worse than that.  It _mutates_ the parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is wrong. Currently, it adds the elements of the parameter `Map hint` in itself, that will end doing nothing.

The code should be:

```
public void addRenderingHints(Map hints) {
    this.hints.putAll(hints);
}
```

The difference is when using `this.hints`. Using `this` refers to the fields in the class.

Answer (score 1):

It adds contents of the `Map` referenced by the **parameter** to itself. That is, it calls `putAll` on the parameter, passing the parameter in. The instance member is not involved at all.

This is not likely what was intended. They probably meant:

```
this.hints.putAll(hints);
```

That calls `putAll` on the **instance field**, passing in the **parameter**.

---

This is one reason why some Java lint tools and IDEs have an option to require that you prefix instance fields and methods with `this.`, even though the language specification makes it optional (er, when they're not shadowed by local parameters). In any case, hopefully any decent IDE would warn you that the parameter was shadowing the instance field.